# Support for @ElementCollection in hibernate tools hbm2ddl

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-tools, hibernate3-maven-plugin

I am trying to use the jpa2 feature @ElementCollection for a List of Strings in my Entity. I am using the hibernate3-maven-plugin to carry out the hbm2ddl task.

However it seems the version of hibernate tools used by the plugin does not know how to deal with the @ElementCollection annotation can anyone give me pointers about what version of hibernate tools I need to use so that this is not the case. Should it just be a case of specifying the correct version of hibernate tools?

```
 <plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  <dependencies>
<dependency>
     <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
     <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
     <version>8.3-603.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>
     <version>3.2.4.GA</version>
     <type>jar</type>
     <scope>runtime</scope>
 </dependency>
```

> [INFO] Trace
>   org.hibernate.MappingException: Could
>   not determine type for:
>   java.util.List, at table: mystuff, for
>   columns:
>   [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(stuffs)]

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just have a version mismatch with the plugin. hibernate3-maven-plugin has a dependency on Hibernate 3.3.1.GA.

You could try and ignore that on the hibernate3-maven-plugin and get the correct version (3.5.3 Final might work) manually.

Maybe setting the annotation on the field instead of setter might help as well.

Comment: Would love to see how to fix this!

Comment: The following [link](http://blog.flurdy.com/2010/07/orghibernatemappingexception-could-not.html) provided the steps required to get the plugin working as required.

I was going down the wrong track of trying to change the hibernate tools version in the plugin when I updated to the most recent version of org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager to the plugin it worked.